# How to change the Solution Property in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

Hi This may seem easy.

When create a MFC project/solution in Visual Studio 2010, I **unchecked** the "ActiveX Controls".

Later I change my mind and want to add "ActiveX Controls", however, I can not find it in the Properties of the MFC project.

[image]

Where can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change your mind afterwards, these options are used only to **generate** a project.

The best way (to me) is to generate two dummy projects one with and one without ActiveX, compare the two dummy projects and make the necessary changes in your own project.

Comment: I do it all the time. Project are text file, just like source code. It will basically add a few includes to `stdafx.h` and a few lines to `MainFrm.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the configuration AFTER you created the code.

There is not much to do:

1. Add to the main application in InitIstance

`if (!AfxOleInit())
{
    AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
    return FALSE;
}
AfxEnableControlContainer();`

1. Add to ExitInstance

`AfxOleTerm(FALSE);`

You can look what the wizard is doing if you examine the code of the templates.
Look into:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio n\VC\VCWizards\AppWiz\MFC\Application\templates\1033\

You find a root.cpp and there are place holders and special [!if...] sections.
 For your case look for ACTIVEX_CONTROLS. Sometimes this is much faster than doing a diff between two dummy sample projects.